# How to apply \begin{array} here

Tags: align, arrays

Please, how to align the following

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{arabbook}
%%%%%%%%%%% packages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{arabtex} 
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}% R ensemble des nombres reels
\usepackage{graphicx}% ajouter des photos
\usepackage{pstricks}% pour dessiner
%%%%%%%%%%%% ab3ad AlsfhA
\textwidth= 15truecm % 
\textheight= 22.27truecm % 
\hoffset= -1.5 cm%truecm %
\voffset= -1.5 cm%truecm %
%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
% `dm Alt^skyl 
\novocalize
% bdAyt Alw_tyqT
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\Large \RL{'a}
\end{center}
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccc}
\RL{'isqA.t} &&&&&&&& 2.1 &&&&& Projection\\
\RL{'in`kAs} &&&&&&&& 2.1 &&&&& R\acute{e}flexion\\
\RL{'iltwA' } &&&&&&&&  2.1 &&&&& Torsion
\end{array}
$$
\begin{center}
\Large \RL{t}
\end{center}
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccc}
\RL{tnA.zr} &&&&&&&& 2.1 &&&&&  Sym\acute{e}trie
\end{array}
$$
\begin{center}
\Large \RL{z}
\end{center}
$$
\RL{zmrT 'asAsyT}\hspace{3.15cm} 8.3  \hspace{0.95cm}\text{Groupe Fondamentale}
 $$
\begin{center}
\Large \RL{s} 
\end{center}
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
\RL{sbyl} \hspace{0.5cm}&&&&&& 8.3 &&&&&&&  chemin\\
\RL{sbyl m.glq} &&&&&& 8.3 &&&&&&&  lacet
\end{array}
$$
\begin{center}
\Large \RL{.t}
\end{center}
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccc}
\RL{.twbwlwjyA} &&&&& 2.1 &&&&& Topologie
\end{array}
$$
\begin{center}
\Large \RL{`} 
\end{center}
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccc}
\RL{`qdT} &&&&&&& 1.2 &&&&&& Noeud \\
\RL{`qdT mrAT} &&&&&&  4.2 &&&&&& Noeud mirroir  \\
\RL{`dad AltdA_hlAt} &&&&&&  12.2 &&&&&& nombre d'entrelacement\\
\RL{`dad Aljswr} &&&&&& 11.2 &&&&&& Nombre de ponts \\
\RL{`dad AltfkykAt} &&&&&& 10.2 &&&&&&     Nombre de dénouement 
\end{array}
$$
\begin{center}
 \Large \RL{.g}
\end{center}  
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\RL{.gms} & 2.1 & immersion 
\end{array}
$$
 \begin{center}
\Large \RL{l}
\end{center} 
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\RL{lAmt.hwl} & 2.3 & Invariant
\end{array}
$$
\begin{center}
\Large \RL{m}
\end{center}
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
\RL{ mt`did `qd} && 2.2 && Entrelacs \\
\RL{ m_h.ta.t} &&  3.2 && Diagramme \\
\RL{ mst^sAkl} && 2.1 && Homéomorphisme
\end{array}
$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's `\RL`? It's not a standard command.

Comment: @egreg i'm working on arabtex

Comment: @egreg you must use \usepackage{arabtex}

Comment: please make your example a complete document so that people can run it, currently we can not run it and you have given no indication of the problem,. But why are you using `array` here at all ?? The entries such as `Sym\acute{e}trie` are text not math  using `\acute`  there is clearly wrong as that is a math accent.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  i edited my message , please help me

Comment: @egreg i edited my message please help me

Comment: the code is so weird I can not even start to guess what output you intend, you need to describe what you want the output to look like. I do not think you want display math or `array` at all  (there seems to be no math in the document) perhaps you want `tabular` (the text mode version of `array` but why `\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccc}` with so many columns, almost all of which are empty, and why have arrays with only one row, there is nothing to align if you only have one row????

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to guess from the markup what the intended output ism but you should not be using math mode. perhaps something likke this but maybe the alignment of the arabic is wrong (it is being set as an arabic insert in a left-to right para) but I don't really now enough arabtex markup to change it

[image]

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{arabbook}
%%%%%%%%%%% packages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{arabtex} 
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}% R ensemble des nombres reels
\usepackage{graphicx}% ajouter des photos
\usepackage{pstricks}% pour dessiner
%%%%%%%%%%%% ab3ad AlsfhA
\textwidth= 15truecm % 
\textheight= 22.27truecm % 
\hoffset= -1.5 cm%truecm %
\voffset= -1.5 cm%truecm %
%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
% `dm Alt^skyl 
\novocalize
% bdAyt Alw_tyqT
\begin{document}

\centering
\section*{\RL{'a}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{.4\textwidth}cp{.4\textwidth}@{}}
\mbox{\RL{'isqA.t}} & 2.1 & Projection\\
\mbox{\RL{'in`kAs}} & 2.1 & R\'eflexion\\
\mbox{\RL{'iltwA'}} &  2.1 & Torsion
\end{tabular*}

\section*{\RL{t}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{.4\textwidth}cp{.4\textwidth}@{}}
\mbox{\RL{tnA.zr}} & 2.1 &  Sym\'etrie
\end{tabular*}

\section*{\RL{z}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{.4\textwidth}cp{.4\textwidth}@{}}
\mbox{\RL{zmrT 'asAsyT}}& 8.3  &Groupe Fondamentale
\end{tabular*}

\section*{\RL{s}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{.4\textwidth}cp{.4\textwidth}@{}}
\mbox{\RL{sbyl}} & 8.3 &  chemin\\
\mbox{\RL{sbyl m.glq}} & 8.3 &  lacet
\end{tabular*}

\section*{\RL{.t}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{.4\textwidth}cp{.4\textwidth}@{}}
\mbox{\RL{.twbwlwjyA}} & 2.1 & Topologie
\end{tabular*}


\section*{\RL{`}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{.4\textwidth}cp{.4\textwidth}@{}}
\mbox{\RL{`qdT}} & 1.2 & Noeud \\
\mbox{\RL{`qdT mrAT}} &  4.2 & Noeud mirroir  \\
\mbox{\RL{`dad AltdA_hlAt}} &  12.2 & nombre d'entrelacement\\
\mbox{\RL{`dad Aljswr}} & 11.2 & Nombre de ponts \\
\mbox{\RL{`dad AltfkykAt}} & 10.2 &     Nombre de dénouement 
\end{tabular*}
 \section*{\RL{.g}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{.4\textwidth}cp{.4\textwidth}@{}}
\mbox{\RL{.gms}} & 2.1 & immersion 
\end{tabular*}
\section*{\RL{l}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{.4\textwidth}cp{.4\textwidth}@{}}
\mbox{\RL{lAmt.hwl}} & 2.3 & Invariant
\end{tabular*}

\section*{\RL{m}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{.4\textwidth}cp{.4\textwidth}@{}}
\mbox{\RL{ mt`did `qd}} & 2.2 & Entrelacs \\
\mbox{\RL{ m_h.ta.t}} &  3.2 & Diagramme \\
\mbox{\RL{ mst^sAkl}} & 2.1 & Homéomorphisme
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

For typesetting arabic these days I would seriously consider not using latex and 8bit fonts, but switch to xelatex and use modern opentype arabic fonts.

Comment: it is not good like this

Comment: why the arabic sentences are not in the same line?

Comment: @PolineSandra sure but I can't read the text so "not good" isn't enough description of what is wrong, as I say you probably want the first column set in arabic using right to left lines but I don't know the arabtex markup to do that,  but at least you have a chance of correcting it, the markup  in the question was so weird I had to take a complete guess of the intention.  You certainly want no math mode and no use of `array`

Comment: i don't understand : as I say you probably want the first column set in arabic using right to left lines but I don't know the arabtex markup to do that, but at least you have a chance of correcting it,

Comment: the arabic sentence must be in the same line with french sentences

Comment: @PolineSandra sorry I mean that I know the setting of the arab phrases in the first column is incorrect but I do not know in arabtex how to say you want a `p` column with right to left arabic, the above is a p column with left to right english setting but then an insert `\RL` of right to keft, so th elines align the wrong way (you could use `\raggedleft` but that isn't really correct.  but this version shows the correct markup, that is tabular for text , not array, if you can correct the arabtex usage

Comment: where i must put \raggedleft?

Comment: @PolineSandra I added a workound for the lines, you could put `\raggedleft` before those `\mbox`

Comment: still the same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77485/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-poline-sandra).